# Given probability of two elements being same in a list, find total number of unique elements

Tags: probability

I have a list L, of numbers ordered randomly. Every number in the list is from  a domain of $1$ to $100$ with the possibility of duplicates. If I point to(without removing) two numbers from the list randomly, the probability that they are same is $x$. The total number of numbers in the list is Size(L). What is the estimation of total number of unique elements in the list?

Eg. [1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 6] 
Total number of unique elements is 5.

We can make assumptions about the distribution. Like, Number of duplicates of 5 in the list may be represented as Uniq(5).

Answer (score 1):

Let $s=Size(L)$.  There are $\frac 12s(s-1)$ pairs of elements, so there are $\frac x2s(s-1)=p$ pairs that match.  $p$ has to be a sum of triangular numbers, but we can't be sure how they are distributed.  For example, let $s=20, x=1/19,$ so $p=10$.  You could have five of one element and fifteen others, for sixteen unique elements, or you could have ten pairs for ten distinct elements.  Unless we know how the elements were selected we can't say more.